# How can I use chrome devtools?

Tags: google-chrome

I saw a tutorial video that educator used a tool with chrome devtools . I searched for that but I couldn't find that . can you help me ? 
[image: see this picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Chrome DevTools is a set of web developer tools built directly into the Google Chrome browser. DevTools can help you diagnose problems quickly, which ultimately helps you build better websites, faster." https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/

I use it everyday (mostly JavaScript/React + CSS debugging) and this link shows you where to start.

Comment: But still I can't find "script" and "dblclick" like the image that I upload !! how can I access to it ?

Comment: In the tab Sources you can choose any loaded file (html, css, javascript ...) and view its content. In what folder it will be stored that depends very much on what language/languages/libraries you are using ... you have to search.