# Webflow section background

Tags: html, web, css-selectors, visual-web-developer, webflow

[webflow editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRarf.png)
[resulting page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3rQp.png)

I have been trying to reset the backgrounds on my web page to white and I have removed all the section background colors in the webflow editor but for some reason the resulting webpages still have the background colors I have removed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Inspect the element using your browser's [Developer Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51764935/how-can-i-use-chrome-devtools) by right-clicking on the element and choosing "Inspect".
2. Look in the computed CSS panel to see which which class the offending style is being inherited from.
3. Style that class so that the element is inheriting the desired style.

Answer (score 0):

Shawn's suggestions are really good. Highly recommend starting with them.

In addition:

1. Check for divs/layers which has absolute positioning. They could be used as background fillers
2. Check for animations/interactions. There could be custom animations created which on load or on scroll change specific elements' background colours.

But to tell clearly, you could provide a read-only link from Webflow. It would be easier to diagnose